# Decoding compressed response (Libcurl)

Tags: http, gzip, libcurl, deflate

I'm asking for a compressed response from the web server using:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");
```

But the answer i receive in

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &writeBuffer);
```

Is still compressed (gzip), so I'm getting exceptions trying to read it.
How can I make Libcurl decompress the response automatically?

Comment: I'm using Libcurl 7.24.0 and also when I try curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, ""); the server gets Accept-Encoding: identity

Comment: Ok, I understand that I need to add zlib to my MSVC project, it just that I didn't figured out how to do it yet..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your libcurl library was compiled with the following preprocessor directives defined:

```
HAVE_ZLIB_H; HAVE_ZLIB; HAVE_LIBZ;
```

This will require 'zlib.h' to be available.